# how to populate backbone collection from json using button

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have large collection of json objects which I retrieve through a search function, though depends on the search string, the output can go up to more than thousand of arrays which I populate into a list. Within mobile environment this become a hassle and memory consuming once I add touchmove, touchstart and touchend to each object. I found solution to this that there's a minimal way of showing object using backbone.js and with trigger such as button this could become robust. though I don't know how to go foward with it. This is working example without the button. And how I shoud do this?

```
<script>
    //model - define value objects.
    var Client = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'cole',
            age: '12'
        }
    });
    //collection - load json
    var ClientCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            model: Client
        },
        model: Client,
        url: './json/test.json',
    //override parse due to json format. point to "items"
        parse: function (response, xhr) {
            return response.items;
        }
    });
    //view. init collection. listen for data to be loaded. render.
    var ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this.collection = new ClientCollection();
            this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
            this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function () {
            //append to html here ...
            //alert(this.collection.at(0).get("name"));
            //alert(this.collection.length)
            for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.length; i++) {
                $('#append-el').append('<li>' + this.collection.at([i]).get("name") + '; ' + this.collection.at([i]).get("age") + '</li>')
            }

        }
    });
    var clientView = new ClientView();

</script>

<div id = "append-el"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to your view pointing to your button with the events hash, something like this

```js
,events {
   "click #buttonID" : "fillCollection"// <- this is a method name
}
```

and then create this method and trigger a [`collection.fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch), like this

```js
,fillCollection: function(){
    this.collection.fetch();
}
```

Comment: There is no need in this.render() cause this.collection.fetch() triggers "reset" event when the model data returns from the server  [fetch](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

Comment: yeah I found the solution is to have events listener together with fetch(), fetch will do the job retrieving data from json. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you well then this should work:

```
var ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#append-el',
    events: {
        'click button': 'onButtonClick'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.collection = new ClientCollection();
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.renderClients);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        //append to html here ...   
        this.$el.append('<button type="button">Fetch clients</button><ul class="clients"></ul>');
    },
    renderClients: function() {
        var $ul = this.$('ul.clients').empty();
        this.collection.each(function(client) {
            $ul.append('<li>' + client.get("name") + '; ' + client.get("age") + '</li>');
        });
    },
    onButtonClick: function(e) {
        this.collection.fetch();
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah this solution did the trick, but the el: 'div#append-el' won't trigger the whole function, if I change it to el: 'body' the whole script works,  I'm a bit clueless on that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to fetch thousands of items at once. Limit it to 100 max 200 hundred. Then I would start listening to scrolling on the list a fetch the rest of the items on as needed basis (you can automatically load them once the user approaches the end of the scrolled area or just place a "Load more" button at the bottom).

There are several paginator plugins for Backbone or you can simply limit the number of rendered element within the render() function.